# Get into the router setting without knowing the password

Tags: router, passwords, connection, wifi-configuration

So my father has changed the router passwords, and programed the router to turn my wifi connection off automaticly at some times, for example at night. I wanted to know if there is any way I can  trick this feature? Can i change my ip in some way, the router won't recognize my ip, so my new ip would have internet connection? Is it any way i can get into the router settings and turn that feature off without knowing the router password? Would be happy if I could get replies as soon as possible!

Comment: There's probably a way to reset it maybe. What router do you have?

Comment: Do your homework!

Comment: Have you tried this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7m7ewouLQXA

Comment: Ask your father for the password

Comment: I'm not sure that cracking/hacking an administators' setup without their consultation is really something that needs to be explored on this SE.

Comment: Circumventing legitimate security is not something we actively encourage here at Super User.

Answer (score 2):

If he is controlling your access time via the router, it's likely that he is doing so via your MAC address. In that case, changing your IP address isn't going to work.

What you *can* do however, is [spoof your MAC address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_spoofing). This will effectively tell the router that your computer is a new device connecting and to give it full access to the internet. This is assuming that the router doesn't have a whitelist of MAC addresses that are allowed to connect.

If the above fails, then you're going to need to get into the router itself. You can do that in a number of ways:

- Performing a factory reset, which is extremely likely to get yourself caught.
- Social Engineering, trick him into giving you the password.
- Hack in.

NOTE: The above methods are pretty much guaranteed to destroy any trust you may have built up. Earning permission is a much better way to go about this.

Comment: The problem you're more than likely to encounter with simply spoofing the address is that any router setup to only allow access at certain times is most likely using a MAC whitelist. If spoofing is going to work he'd need to spoof a specific MAC already being used. Not that this isn't going to be a possibility, just be aware that any old MAC will not do. You need a MAC that has the perms you need.

Comment: I did mention that spoofing would only work if there wasn't a whitelist.

Comment: Yep and I pointed out that this is not actually a deal breaker as long as you use a MAC on the list which has the perms you want.